# firebase auth change being triggered continuously?

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
import firebase from './firebase';

const auth = firebase.auth();

function display(user) {
    if (user) {
        window.location = 'home.html';
    }
    else {
        window.location = 'login.html'; 
    }
}
export default function onAuthChange() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(display);
}
```

This code causes my page to refresh again and again. How do I fix this? I am using vanilla js.

I tried an altogether different solution that uses `auth().currentUser === null` to check and load the correct page but it comes with its own problems in that the page takes time to find out the current state which is initally null on refresh.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by setting `window.location`. It basically refreshes your page. This causes the user to be logged out and re-logged in automatically.

If you are using Angular you can solve this with routing, which does not reload the page.

Comment: I am using vanilla js

Comment: Then you need to make sure Firebase has time to automatically log in the user again before you check.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `onAuthStateChanged()` returns a trinary value, not binary.  It will return either:

**`undefined`**: The SDK has loaded but hasn't checked user's authentication status yet.

**`null`**: User is definitely unauthenticated.

**`firebase.auth.User`**: User is authenticated.

When you do a simple `if (user is truthy) {}` test the user will always appear unauthenticated on first load.

The following changes should fix it:

```
import firebase from './firebase';

const auth = firebase.auth();

function display(user) {
    if (typeof user === "undefined") {
      // SDK has loaded but we don't know the user's real status yet
      return;
    } else if (user === null) {
        // User is definitely unauthenticated
        window.location = 'login.html';
    } else {
        // User is authenticated
        window.location = 'home.html';
    }
}
export default function onAuthChange() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(display);
}
```

Comment: Hey Brian. You're saying that "undefined: The SDK has loaded but hasn't checked user's authentication status yet." I used to think this too until one of the engineers recently corrected me, and I since then verified it back to the 2.x releases of the SDKs. The `onAuthStateChanged` is only called for the first time when the SDK has completed its initial check. So while `firebase.auth().currentUser` may be in this initial state, it will never fire the auth state change listener for this.

Comment: Awesome news @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the update!  I think I learned this initially from a post Doug Stevenson wrote while researching a similar problem.

Comment: I think both Doug and myself got schooled there. :)

Comment: @MCode Give it a try, it's tough to say with the limited code you posted. The above is a basic version of how I implement Firebase Auth.